# HTML link in an unordered list not changing color when hovering

Tags: html, css, debugging

I'm trying to create a guitar-related website and learn html and css in the process, but I've ran into a problem: I've created a list where all the elements are links and I'd like for them to be white but turn yellow when hovered over. I can't seem to accomplish both of these objectives at the same time. Either they're always white or they turn yellow when hovered over but otherwise stay purple.

I've tried creating the hover function as an id (using it only once, as you do with id's), creating a div with all the necessary classes, inserting the hover function into the ul list or into each of the list elements or into the link descriptions. Nothing has worked so far.

HTML and CSS (separate files):

```
<div class="ul2 alink1 ahover1 avisited1">

<ul>

<li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_guitar" target="_blank" 
>Electric guitars</a></li>

<li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_guitar" target="_blank" 
>Acoustic guitars</a></li>

<li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-acoustic_guitar" 
target="_blank" >Semi-acoustic/semi-hollow guitars</a></li>

<li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guitar_synthesizer#MIDI_guitars" 
target="_blank" >MIDI-guitars</a></li>

</ul>

</div>

</body>


.body {
background-color:black;
}
.alink1 a:link {
text-decoration:none;
font-size:26px;
font-style:italic;
color:white;
}
.ahover1 a:hover {
color:yellow;
}
.avisited1 a:visited {
color:white;
}
.ul2 {
list-style-type:circle;
color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to pseudo selectors, they work in a specific order. So the the hierarchy is as follows:

- :link
- :visited
- :hover, :focus
- :active

What you want to achieve can be done with these simple modifications:

```
.alink1 a {
text-decoration:none;
font-size:26px;
font-style:italic;
color:white;
}
.ahover1 a:hover {
color:yellow;
}
```

Remove the a:visited selector from your CSS as it's not needed, remove the a:link and have it as an a tag only.

I believe this is what you are after.